# How to convert a list which contains float values with single quotes to a list which has those values without singlequotes in python?

Tags: python, list, floating-point, precision, pyscripter

Input list

`res = ['1.000000e+000', '2.000000e+000', '1.000000e+000', '2.000000e+000']`

output list should be like this

`res = [1.000000e+000, 2.000000e+000, 1.000000e+000, 2.000000e+000]`

Can you please suggest me how to produce this desired output using python

Answer (score 3):

Those are not "float values with single quotes". Those are strings. You can do

```
res = list(map(float,res))
```

or a full comprehension

```
res = [float(i) for i in res]
```

Comment: when i use the above code i get the output as [[1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0]]

Comment: how to convert these values as its without single quotes i mean these are double values

Comment: [1.0,2.0,1.0,2.0] is exactly what you should get.

Answer (score 1):

just iterate over the elements in the list and cast the strings as floats.
In this case I used a list comprehension (basically a loop):

```
res = [float(i) for i in res]
```